# BackgroundScheduler in a flask+gunicorn app being run for each worker, not just once

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, gunicorn

I have a webapp using Flask, Gunicorn and Nginx. In accordance with the documentation, I'm using a worker count larger than the number of CPUs.

However, when I have a scheduled task that writes to a file, it's being rewritten once by each worker, instead of being written only once overall.

**the gunicorn configuration**

```
command = /home/brun0/infraestruturas/venv/bin/gunicorn -w 3 app:app
```

if i use 1 instead of 3 workers it only prints once (like i want) but i dont know if its good to do this with only 1 worker

**flask app**

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

def trains():
    try:
        data = list(getRequest())
        trainList = getTrain(data)
        delayedSet = getDelayedCSV(trainList)
        delayedCounter(delayedSet)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)



scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(func=trains, trigger='interval', minutes=10 ,max_instances=100, misfire_grace_time=None)
scheduler.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: Please post the code from your script so we can better answer the question. Gunicorn should assign a single worker to a single request so need to see the code.

Comment: the code is realy big ... more than one file.
you want me to show you the function that does the request?

Comment: That would probably be helpful, along with the command you are using to run gunicorn or your custom gunicorn config if you are using one.

Comment: Ok @NateDellinger its better now? i am using supervisor too

Comment: @BrunoTeixeira,...as a rule, what we want here is a [mcve] -- *the shortest possible code* that can be used to reproduce the same problem (and test whether a fix succeeds) without needing any changes before it's ready to run, complete with enough logging (but preferably only just enough!) to be able to tell whether the fix succeeded.

Comment: that said, each request should only go to one worker; if you have the same request being processed more than once, that's... very unusual.

Comment: ...so, a good place to start is to build the shortest possible flask+gunicorn "hello world" program you can, and then figure out what needs to be added to it to make it demonstrate the issue.

Comment: thanks for the words @CharlesDuffy . i think the issue is already demonstrated by adding the code and the gunicorn command.
the only thing that is doing three times is when writing to a file and when i run that same piece of code, running localy it only writes in the file once so the only problem i see is the 3 workers in gunicorn

Comment: We gotta see the @route which is utilizing `getRequest`. With flask you can pretty easily create a single file which reproduces your problem with the app initiation and route setup in one file. It could be something strange is going on with your yield.

Comment: @NateDellinger there you go dude. can you confirm?

Comment: Oh haha. You are using a scheduler. The function run is not related to any request. Gunicorn forks multiple workers which starts up multiple of your background schedulers. Try adding --preload when launching gunicorn, which should load the app before launching workers and only create one background scheduler. `/home/brun0/infraestruturas/venv/bin/gunicorn -w 3 --preload app:app`